# FirestoreFirebase Query to match a specific data within a specific collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have stored data (UID of every user from Auth table) in the users' collection. I need to get the data from users and match it with the UID of `currentSignedIn` user. If the UID of the currently signed-in user matches with the UIDs in the collection the page may return or navigate to page 1 else navigate to page 2.

Currently, just display the UIDs from the users' collection and the UID of `currentSignedIn` user just to see the data. Now I need a way to match the data and use if-else statements.

Code:

```
@override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}
class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  Future _getDatafromDatabase() async{
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
      .doc().get().then((snapshot) async
  {
    if(snapshot.exists)
      {
        setState(() {
          useruid = snapshot.data()!["useruid"];
        });
      }
  });
}
List<Users> uidofusers = [];
@override
void initState(){
    fetchRecords();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots().listen((records) {
    mapRecords(records);
    });
    super.initState();
}
fetchRecords() async {
var records = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get();
mapRecords(records);
}
mapRecords(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>records) {
var _list = records.docs
    .map((item)=>Users(
    useruid: item['useruid'],
)
).toList();
setState(() {
  uidofusers = _list;
});
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: const Text("Update Profile", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
                onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
              ),

            ]
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: uidofusers.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(uidofusers[index].useruid),
              subtitle: Text(uid!),

            );
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the user's document with the UID of the user as its document ID (which is recommended), you can get it with:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
  .doc(uidOfTheUser)
  .get()
```

If you store the user's document under a randomly generated document ID, with a field `useruid` with the UID, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to get the document:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
  .where("useruid", isEqualTo: uidOfTheUser)
  .get()
```

In the latter case there may be [multiple documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) matching the condition, so you get back a `QuerySnapshot` that you need to loop over.